# heroku: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, heroku, repository, hosting

I'm hosting on Heroku. When I push:

```
git push master Heroku
```

I get the error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com: etc ...'
```

Comment: The above error can come up when you have an incorrect branch name, so for others facing the same issue it would be helpful to double check that.

Comment: It also happens when you didn't commit anything yet. Did you `commit` after `adding`?

Comment: for anyone coming here, this happened to me too, and the cause was git renaming _master_ to _main_, starting 10-01-2020 according to [this](https://github.com/github/renaming#on-october-1-2020-newly-created-repositories-will-default-to-main), maybe heroku jumped the gun ¯\\(º.º)/¯

Comment: Try to run it from the beginning: ```git config --global```.

Comment: `git push heroku main` maybe required

Answer (score 317):

This is work for me:-

```
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you edit it to explain *why* your version works (`git push <remote> <local ref>:<remote branch>` syntax) and the OP's version doesn't.

Comment: This is also undesired behavior if one wants to push to the remote heroku master and trigger a build, but do not want the local master branch tampered with.

Comment: It would be especially useful to know why this works, when the Heroku guide itself says to use the other one and the other one doesn't. :|

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196578/433717) is why it works.

Comment: Worked! Does one have to understand that?

Comment: Worked! for me. Can someone explain this?

Comment: It works because `master` as second parameter to `git push` is the remote default branch in heroku and has to be set in some cases like in this `src refspec`? The local branch is the one that you `checkout`ed and can be different from `master`
.

Answer (score 79):

I have experienced the problem.
I solved this problem like this

1. make file whatever
2. commit
3. push

   ```
    $ touch readme

    $ git add .

    $ git commit -m "init"

    $ git push heroku master
   ```

I don't know why.

Comment: `git push heroku main` with this solution worked for me

Answer (score 38):

At first glance it looks like you have got your `master` and `Heroku` parameters round the wrong way because the first parameter to `git push` should be the name of the remote repository, the second is refspec (normally a branch). You are more likely to have a branch called `master` and a remote called `Heroku`. But I would expect you to get a different error message if that were the case, something like:

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The error message you are seeing implies that there is no local `master` branch. That would be the case if you haven't made any commits yet because git doesn't create the branch until the first commit. You can check this by running:

```
git show-ref
```

You should see a line containing `refs/heads/master` if you have a master branch. If not then try running:

```
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

You can also find out what remotes you have available with:

```
git remote -v
```

If you have a remote called Heroku you should see something like:

```
Heroku  git@heroku.youraccount:yourproject.git (fetch)
Heroku  git@heroku.youraccount:yourproject.git (push)
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Turned out I had created a git branch, but I thought I had switched over the the master branch. Apparently there were conflicts in the branches I needed to resolve before I could successfully pushing to Heroku.

Comment: Had to use double quotes: `git commit -m "Initial commit"`

Comment: Also, for anyone still wondering, it could also be that you used master instead of main... Or the other way around

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

`git push heroku main`

[Source here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app)

Answer (score 33):

I got this error when trying to push to Heroku when I wasn't on my local master branch.

I resolved it with

`git push heroku my_branch_name:master`

and replacing `my_branch_name` with the name of the git branch I was on.  I think this tells Heroku to receive this local branch on Heroku's master branch.

Comment: Thanks so much! My case is, my branch is called "develop", while heroku's deploy branch is "master". Hence, by simply running git push heroku master didn't work for me, but running git push heroku develop:master worked! You saved my day! Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this happened because I had nothing to push.  I had forgotten to do a "git add" first.  As soon as I did a "git add" then "git commit" for actual content, the push worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

This is a late answer, but might help someone.

instead of this:

```
git push master Heroku
```

try:

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 7):

actually, i needed to create a file, otherwise commit was empty.

```
touch readme.md
```

Comment: you can `git commit -m dummy --allow-empty` instead of changing files

Answer (score 4):

Starting Oct. 1st, 2020 Github defaults to "main" instead of "master" as the default branch name when you create a new repository. If you've followed all the usual steps then take a look at your current branches ("git branch") and make sure this isn't tripping you up (like it did me).

https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

 git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are writing ->

```
"git push master Heroku"
```

and getting error like->

error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com: etc'

then first type in hyper->

```
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

and then if there is an error like

```
email ,name is not found or something like that
```

then it might be possible that you could'nt sign in heroku page.

first write type in hyper commond line or whatever cmd line you are using

```
git config --global user.email "yourgmail address"
```

then hit enter then type

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

then it will work fine.
if you want to check that it is working fine then type

```
git commit -m 'initial commit'
```

it will take sometime and then write code

```
git push heroku master
```

-------------------------Now everything is solved-TADADAAAA--------------------------
Note-Please write your email address and username  in above code...

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are not on the branch master in your local machine.

checkout to `master` branch/ or `main` branch

and then do

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here after following the step-by-step guide of heroku. To me the problem was solved after creating minimum a file in the repository, committing it and then pushing to heroku again.

Answer (score 2):

Come in late but in my case:

git push git@heroku.com:**appname**.git master

did the trick for me! With **appname** being the name of your heroku app

Answer (score 2):

**First push your changes to the remote branch before pushing to heroku**

```
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

**If you want to push a branch which is not the master branch to heroku**

```
git push origin development_branch
git push heroku development_branch:master
```

Answer (score 2):

For me I need to commit files first

```
git commit -m "First commit adding files"
```

then

```
git push heroku master
```

Also check whether, is your master branch is `main` then you need to use

```
git push heroku main
```

Similarly, if you want to push any of your branch which is not a master then use

```
git push heroku <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

[For an existing Heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-heroku-app)

```
heroku git:remote -a <APP-NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an answer which is to the point of the question

You are facing this error because **Git create master branch only after commit to your local repo**. If you just initialize repo then there is no master.

So how do you fix it?

Just add and commit at least one change to your repo and re-run push command. You can add and commit a simple .gitignore file as well likewise stated in other answers

Answer (score 0):

The error on my terminal
"testpry git:(ft-heroku-deployment-170679745) git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/guarded-taiga-41995.git'"

Solution: You need to check the name of the branch you are working on. In this case, it is "ft-heroku-deployment-170679745"

The right push command is $ `git push heroku ft-heroku-deployment-170679745`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. 
For me the problem occurred because I hadn't signed into git correctly. 
Before you can push code to the master branch, you must have first made your initial commit with the command `git commit -m "My first commit"`. You may have gotten this response when trying to do that (like I got):

> git: fatal unable to auto-detect email address (got "some wrong
>   email").

If that was the response you got, you must now enter your desired git email and username with the commands:

`git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`

`git config --global user.name "Your Username"`

After you've done that, try the push command again

`git push heroku master`

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was having two lockfiles `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`. Deleting one of them solved the problem. Here is the error message:

```
 !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
       Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
       but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
       dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
       packages or subtle bugs in production.
       - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
         the yarn.lock file.
         $ git rm yarn.lock
       - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
         the package-lock.json file.
         $ git rm package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you are pushing the same app name as in Heroku.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if the above solutions did not work check the hidden .git folder. in .git folder check for file packed-refs
it should have a hash key referencing to refs/remotes/heroku/main
if this is not there then. you can follow below steps

- step1: login to heroku cli
- step2: run cmd heroku git:clone -a your-app-name
- step3: perform git push

to get list of heroku apps. you can run below cmd
heroku apps

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

```
 $ git init 

 $ git add .

 $ git commit -m "init"

 $ git branch -M main

 $ git push heroku main
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check if heroku is added as remote: git remote -v
   you should see something like this:

heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yourapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yourapp.git (push)

2. if there is none then set the remote - git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:MyApp.git (in old git versions ) or heroku git:remote -a example-app (in new version of git)
3. git push heroku master (old git)
   git push heroku main (new git )

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue after pushing a copy of my local repository to a GitHub repo.

Prior to that, `git push heroku master` from my local repo was working fine to deploy to Heroku.

After pushing to GitHub however, `git push heroku master` began giving the `error: src refspec master does not match any` message, and I had to `git push heroku main` to successfully deploy.

Apparently pushing a copy to GitHub changed the branch name of the local repo from `master` to `main`.