# git push heroku master rejected with error

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I tried `git push heroku master`
 It ends with `error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-eyrie-78536.git'`

Any ideas welcomed what should I do to get app deployed on heroku.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595874/i-want-make-push-and-get-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any

Comment: tried each and every answer on that question problem is still the same

Comment: what's your heroku remote ? check with git remote -v

Comment: heroku  https://git.heroku.com/mighty-eyrie-78536.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/mighty-eyrie-78536.git (push)