# Heroku issue error: failed to push some refs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app with Heroku

Every time I type in the terminal

```
git push heroku master
```

I get

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@heroku.com/deucex1.git'
```

I don't know how to fix this and I don't know where "'ssh://git@heroku.com/deucex1.git'" is coming from, I never created anything with that name, but whatever it is, I want it out of my system. How do I do this?

Now when i type in
    git push heroku master

I get

```
 !  No such app as deucex1.
 !  
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: ee:8e:6a:22:cf:81:91:bb:3a:b0:b5:c6:36:84:a5:1d

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I get rid of the deucex1 thing?

New problem

When I enter

```
git push heroku master

remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:        sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to sale9.
remote: 
To ssh://heroku.com/sale9.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@heroku.com/sale9.git'
```

I then entered in the terminal

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'
```

and that didn't work

Got that working, but when I type in

git push heroku master

again, it just shows me

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Shouldn't i be getting more than that?

Now the tutorial asks me to enter

```
git push
```

but i get

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595874/i-want-make-push-and-get-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you most likely had the remote added from a `heroku create`.

To show the list of remotes tied to your repo use: `git remote -v`

In your case you will most likely show:

```
heroku  ssh://git@heroku.com/deucex1.git (fetch)
heroku  ssh://git@heroku.com/deucex1.git (push)
```

To be able to deploy to heroku from git you set up remotes to be able to push/pull to/from them `git push heroku master`

There are typically 2 types of protocols you can use `ssh` or `https`. In your case `ssh://heroku_git_url.git`.

If you really wish to remove your remote you can use: `git remote rm heroku`. However, if you are looking to deploy to heroku either setup SSH or use `heroku login` with the https protocol.

I would highly recommend you take a look at Heroku's deployment guide: [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

**Update**

`deucex1` is your application on Heroku.

If you already have an app created on Heroku you can simply remove your current heroku remote `git remote rm heroku` and add your app remote into your git `heroku git:remote -a APP_NAME`.

Comment: I don't have an app name deucex1 and it keeps popping up

Comment: heroku thinks you have a app `deucex1` based on your remote `ssh://git@heroku.com/deucex1.git`. Add the correct remote to your git remotes by using the commands in my comment. (if you have ssh, make sure its setup correctly). https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: Heroku does not support SQLite, I'd recommend converting to Postgres

Comment: I added pg gem to gem file, but still getting same results

Comment: Make sure your pushing master to heroku. Otherwise a 'git push -f heroku' might be what your looking for. If you trying to push a another branch other than master, I believe it's 'git push heroku name_of_branch:master'

Comment: I fixed that part i think, now the tutorial tells to type in the terminal    git push    but i'm having problems with that

Comment: please provide tutorial. From your questions, I am assuming all your trying to do is set up a heroku remote and push to it? correct?