# Heroku - Java Maven project depoly - getting application error after complete git push heroku master

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, deployment

I've made a simple Java web app using Maven and I'm trying to deploy it. At first, I've got an error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com: etc ...'
```

however, I found a solution to it here:
[I want make push and get error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595874/i-want-make-push-and-get-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any)

After a while I get the following information in my terminal:

```
remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 11.039 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-03T12:25:10+00:00
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/172M
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 63.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

But when I try *heroku open* or just go the URL there is just info: Application Error.

Here are my heroku logs:

```
2018-10-02T20:55:00.135902+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.225698+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.225698+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.135902+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-02T20:56:51.945196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=97651816-2e92-4196-add2-4cdd5325ca30 fwd="87.206.210.121"
dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T20:56:52.583382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=ca3e65a7-6ef1-4253-a946-2d0cc2e99dc1 fwd="87.20
6.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T20:56:52.583849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=9ae591af-d87c-4224-9832-dff44ea68fd1 fwd="87.20
6.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:24:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:18.147522+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:18.147522+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6d354e57 by user mymail@mail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-03T12:26:45.829110+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=8ebfefdc-d2a9-438d-a224-11f39ec21781 fwd="
87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:26:46.544850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=2af704d0-9703-4fe6-a173-2691ca0
fdd39 fwd="87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:26:46.538716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=11cd4e6d-f850-4687-bc6a-863f30e
667f8 fwd="87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It is my 1st time ever deploying any Java project to the web and I get confused, I don't really understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

After adding Procfile: `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

I've got error again and here are my logs:

```
2018-10-02T20:55:00.135902+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.225698+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.225698+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-02T20:55:00.135902+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-02T20:56:51.945196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=97651816-2e92-4196-add2-4cdd5325ca30 fwd="87.206.210.121"
dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T20:56:52.583382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=ca3e65a7-6ef1-4253-a946-2d0cc2e99dc1 fwd="87.20
6.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-02T20:56:52.583849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=9ae591af-d87c-4224-9832-dff44ea68fd1 fwd="87.20
6.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:24:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:18.147522+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:18.147522+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6d354e57 by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T12:25:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-03T12:26:45.829110+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=8ebfefdc-d2a9-438d-a224-11f39ec21781 fwd="
87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:26:46.544850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=2af704d0-9703-4fe6-a173-2691ca0
fdd39 fwd="87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:26:46.538716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=11cd4e6d-f850-4687-bc6a-863f30e
667f8 fwd="87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:29:48.298049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=4fe1f9d8-e616-4018-8f66-3496194563ee fwd="
87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T12:32:38.432481+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=1b50b089-1aa9-449e-b2f2-7d10182e4955 fwd="
87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T13:01:22.328331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=83248761-74af-4fa4-b26b-f69a9d8da7b6 fwd="
156.114.128.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T13:01:23.283855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=cdc081f2-193a-4490-8e79-7d2c6d8
725a3 fwd="156.114.128.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T13:22:47.102561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=bc9ef838-d37d-4db5-9fb1-338bb5b4cdd2 fwd="
52.32.223.31" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T14:01:33.109607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=bd761dab-f0fa-439f-9141-39581694d536 fwd="
156.114.160.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T20:09:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T20:09:57.925786+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 27d345c5 by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T20:09:57.925786+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user mymail@gmail.com
2018-10-03T20:10:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-10-03T20:34:58.002908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=immense-falls-73440.herokuapp.com request_id=4a875fae-4370-49e0-b1df-4c4ac578294b fwd="
87.206.210.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1):

In your build log it says:

```
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

This means Heroku won't start any processes, which is why you get the "No web processes running" error.

What does your `Procfile` look like? It is probably empty. You'll need something like this:

```
web: java -jar target/myapp.jar
```

Replace the `java` command with the appropriate `java` command to start your app.

Comment: Hello! I'll definitely try your solution as and let know if that worked :)
I was doing it according to this guidance: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally
And there was info:
Deploying to Heroku

A Procfile is not necessary to deploy apps written in most languages supported by Heroku. The platform automatically detects the language, and creates a default web process type to boot the application server.

So I don't even add Procfile to my project.

Comment: I've added following in the Procfile:
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT     target/*.war

Comment: I've added following in the Procfile:

java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT     target/*.war

Saved it as Procfile with no extensions in the main folder of the project then commit and push again, however, I got extended log I've added it to the original post.

Comment: did you see `Procfile declares types -> web` in your build output? try `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Comment: It returns me that:
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type.

So my Procfile is still wrong?