# Git Push heroku master cli

Tags: node.js, heroku-cli

git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/infinite-ravine-36658.git'

I ran into this problem, should i just move it without Heroku ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want make push and get error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595874/i-want-make-push-and-get-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any)

Comment: I think you are not connected to you remote branch. Verify if you are connected using `git remote -v`

Comment: Sorry for late response, both answer correct, thank you.