# Unable to deploy Node application to Heroku: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, heroku

This is the sequence I am doing to deploy an application to Heroku:

- I have a repo with a Node application.
- In project root:

  - `heroku create myappname`
  - `heroku git:remote -a myappname`
  - `git remote -v` (shows both `heroku` and `origin` with fetch and push)
  - `git push heroku master`

This results on an error:

> error: src refspec master does not match any
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myappname.git'

Comment: Does your GitHub repo have the branch: "master'?

Comment: Did you make commits to the master branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want make push and get error: src refspec master does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26595874/2745495)