# Git HEAD referring to branch vs to commit

Tags: git, git-branch

According to [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell):

> In Git, HEAD is a pointer to the local branch you’re currently on.

This is consistent with [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/):

> The HEAD ref is special in that it actually points to another ref. It is a pointer to the currently active branch.

But it [turns out that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196594/336527):

> HEAD is not the latest revision, it's the current revision. Usually, it's the latest revision of the current branch, but it doesn't have to be.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196544/what-are-the-git-concepts-of-head-master-origin#comment10072214_8196594):

> If you check out something older (such as a tag like git checkout v1.1) then your HEAD changes to the commit of that tag. It may not be the latest commit.

So HEAD can point *either* to a branch *or* to a commit. Is the behavior of git commands any different when HEAD refers to branch X compared to when HEAD refers to the actual head commit of branch X? (In C like notation, I'm talking about the case when **HEAD refers to a certain commit vs. when *HEAD refer to the same commit.)

Comment: `HEAD` is a reference pointing to the latest commit of the currently checked out branch, that is all (except when in the detached HEAD state).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I'm talking precisely about the detached `HEAD` case. Only in my case, the detached `HEAD` just happens to point to the most recent commit of the current branch.

Comment: Why does this use case interest/concern you?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Because the fact that `HEAD` can sometimes be a pointer to commit and sometimes a pointer to a pointer to commit feels inconsistent and confusing to me, and it's easier for me to get used to this if I understand the edge case behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you summed up and closed the entire messy debate on what HEAD is. Nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HEAD` is just a reference, much like `master` or (if it exists) `branch`, but with two extra-special properties:

1. `HEAD` is normally a *symbolic* reference (and normally, no other reference is symbolic, although you can make any symbolic reference you like using [`git symbolic-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html)).  A symbolic reference is just a name that contains another name, instead of a hash ID.  When reading or writing a symbolic reference, Git will usually say "oh, well, this one is *symbolic*, so I'll just go read or write the other one now."

   Obviously this can result in an infinite loop:  If reference `a` says "look at `b`" and `b` says "look at `a`", you can chase back and forth forever.  But as long as you either don't do this, or make `HEAD` the *only* symbolic ref, you'll be fine, because you can't make `HEAD` point back to `HEAD`.  Also, symbolic references don't work terribly well: if you make branch `glorp` point to `master` and then ask to delete `glorp`, Git deletes `master` instead!  We'll see when this is actually a good thing in a moment.
2. The literal string `HEAD` is built in to many Git commands, and the file itself is so important—used in so many places—that it's actually a test for whether a directory is itself a Git repository.  This means that if something (such as a particularly untimely crash) wipes out your `HEAD` file, Git will stop believing that your `.git` directory is a repository!  (No big deal, usually: just put the file back and all is well again.)

Whenever you make a *new* commit, the underlying process that Git uses is:<sup>1</sup>

1. Read a commit ID from `HEAD`.  This is the *current commit*: if you're in "detached HEAD" mode, with a raw commit ID in `HEAD`, that's what Git gets.  If you're on a branch, so that `HEAD` contains the name of the branch, Git follows the indirection to the branch name and reads that, giving the tip-most commit of that branch.  Either way, that's the current commit.
2. Write out all the trees needed to make the commit ([`git write-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-write-tree.html)), and write the new commit itself ([`git commit-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html)) with its parent ID set to the ID obtained in step 1 (plus any additional parents needed if this is to be a merge commit), its tree set to the ID obtained here in step 2, and its commit message set to whatever is appropriate.
3. Write the new commit's ID, as obtained from `git commit-tree`, into `HEAD`.  If `HEAD` is symbolic—i.e., you're on a branch—this wites instead to the branch name.  Now the branch name points to the new tip-most commit of the branch!

   But note that, in step 3, if you're in "detached HEAD" mode, Git *still* writes the new ID to `HEAD`.  The result is that `HEAD` points to the tip of the new branch.  In other words, "detached HEAD" mode just means that `HEAD` contains the ID of the tip of an *anonymous* branch.  Adding new commits works exactly the same as always, updating the current branch.  It's just that the current branch has only the name `HEAD`.  (This *is* a name, it's just not the name of a *branch*.  Specifically, all branch names start with `refs/heads/`.  Since `HEAD` doesn't, it's not a *branch* name, it's just a reference.  If a name starts with `refs/remotes/` it's a remote-tracking branch name, and if it starts with `refs/tags/` it's a tag, but `HEAD` doesn't start with anything at all, so it's just a reference.)

Your objection can be rephrased another way as well:

#### But that means many branches can all point to one commit ID!

Exactly.  This is *entirely normal*, and it happens every time you make a new branch:<sup>2</sup>

```
...--o--o--o     <-- HEAD, master
         \
          o      <-- branch
```

If `HEAD` is "detached" and we make a new commit:

```
             o   <-- HEAD
            /
...--o--o--o     <-- master
         \
          o      <-- branch
```

If `HEAD` is *not* detached—if, instead, it points to `master`—and we do `git checkout -b newbr` before we make the new commit, then we start with this instead (and this time I'll draw `HEAD -> newbr` to indicate that `HEAD` is symbolic and points to `newbr`):

```
...--o--o--o     <-- HEAD -> newbr, master
         \
          o      <-- branch
```

and after the commit we have:

```
             o   <-- HEAD -> newbr
            /
...--o--o--o     <-- master
         \
          o      <-- branch
```

Note that in the "before" picture, we had *three* names for the current commit: `HEAD`, `newbr`, and `master` all pointed to it (though `HEAD` had to go through `newbr` first).

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, this is the process for a normal `git commit`.  If you use `git commit --amend`, this process is modified just a bit: instead of reading the ID from `HEAD`, Git looks up the current commit's parent(s), and uses those IDs in step 3.  This means the new commit, once made, has the same parents as the current commit.  By writing the new commit's ID through `HEAD` into the branch, this *appears* to have changed a commit.  But it hasn't, really: it's just shoved the "old current" commit aside.

If you work through an example with two or more branch names pointing to the *same* commit, you'll see exactly how and why using `git commit --amend` on a *published* commit—a commit you've pushed to another repository, and that other people now have by name—can be problematic.  (**Exercise/hint:** How many branch-name references are changed in step 3, when updating `HEAD`?)

<sup>2</sup>Unless, that is, you use `git checkout --orphan`.  What this does is put `HEAD` into the same special state it has in a new, empty repository: `HEAD` now contains the name of a branch that *doesn't actually exist yet*.  That is, it's a symbolic reference to a nonexistent branch.  The three-step commit sequence above knows how to deal with the failure to read an ID from `HEAD`: it makes a new commit with *no* parent, then writes the new ID into `HEAD`, which has the side effect of actually creating the branch.

This solves the bootstrap problem with the new, empty repository: a branch name can only point to an actual commit; but `master`, in a new empty repository, can't point to any commit at all, because there simply aren't any.  So a new repository doesn't actually have a `master` branch until you make the first commit, even though `HEAD` is set up so that you're *on* the `master` branch.

Answer (score 3):

The good definition is that HEAD is always pointing to what is check-outed.

If you are working on a branch, it is pointing to this branch. So, when you check out another branch, HEAD is now pointing to this new branch.

But you could also check out directly a commit, just to verify how things were in the past, and then HEAD is pointing to this commit. You are in what we call a "detached head" state. Read more about that. But, yes this state is not made to work and create new commits. The behaviour of the git command are not really different in this case but the result could be : if you check out a branch, you will lost trace of all your commits created in this state and will have to recover them from the reflog.

And you could see that yourself because HEAD is materialised by the file `.git\HEAD`. Just open the files and see its content...