# Which is the difference between HEAD and Origin on GIT?

Tags: git, github

I pushed some project files to a repository on GitHub by using GIT from the command line. I modified them and added a new file on my local folder. I commit it (I did `git add newFile` and `git commit -m "some text"`), therefore there's nothing more to commit now and the working tree is clean. I typed `Git log` and got the following:

```
commit 532d55b88be3c8cc21ee1f89e08db3fc6c9c0631 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Rob <ennesimo@hotmail.it>
Date:   Fri Jul 12 12:13:55 2019 +0200

    example

commit b9719578146a01a3029e1bf3c6d15b3eb2c5473b
Author: Rob <ennesimo@hotmail.it>
Date:   Fri Jul 12 11:58:17 2019 +0200

    corrected orthography in the low_cost_hotels.json

commit aa8e758e852bb4dde1127b0e2fa256b1f5d67b29
Author: Rob <ennesimo@hotmail.it>
Date:   Fri Jul 12 11:40:04 2019 +0200

    version 2

commit 37e0e292242384afbee80260611ad021ed89ac37 (origin/master)
Author: Rob <ennesimo@hotmail.it>
Date:   Thu Jul 11 12:10:10 2019 +0200

    initial project version - 11 july 2019
```

As you can see here, the first commit reports `(origin/master)`, the last one `(HEAD -> master)`. Why such a difference? I suppose the `origin/master` is my online repository on GitHub, whereas `(HEAD -> master)` signifies that I created a new file on my local folder on my pc and then send it to the `master`, i.e. to the remote repository on GitHub, is it correct reasoning?

Can you explain to me more precisely what "Master" and "HEAD" stand for and why are they named as they are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the git concepts of HEAD, master, origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196544/what-are-the-git-concepts-of-head-master-origin)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+what+is+origin+master+head

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is that `origin/master` is currently pointing to the bottom commit `37e0e292`, while `HEAD` is pointing to the latest top commit `532d55b8`.  All this means is that since you have synched your local branch with the remote, you have made three additional local commits.

Keep in mind that `origin/master` is a local *tracking* branch.  What this means is that it exists to track what it perceives to be the latest state of the `master` branch on the actual GitHub repo.  This makes sense, because, absent any other information, the remote is now three commits *behind* the version of `master` which have locally.

If you were to sync up the remote branch via a `git fetch`, then the `git log` output might change (or it might not).

Comment: ( Check Credit Reference: stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6888123 ) There is No such thing as "local tracking branch". However, it would be accurate to say that there is a "locally located" "remote-tracking branch" which is "locally located" on the local developer's computer and in this case would be the origin/master

Answer (score 2):

*HEAD* is a reference to the last commit in the currently checked out branch.
The commit with *HEAD->master* is what the local *master* branch is pointing to. *origin/master* refers to the remote *master* branch. Once you push the commit to the remote must branch, Git will indicate that *origin/master* has the commit.

[image]