# Meaning of `HEAD -> main` vs `origin/HEAD`?

Tags: git, branch, git-commit

When I do `git log --oneline` on a local branch that is ahead of `origin` by a few commits, I get something like:

```
ff0dc35 (HEAD -> main) Style headers
08183f1 Fix <Title>s
071d82e (origin/main, origin/HEAD) Style list items
9b24f09 Add style.css
b9fd2fa Add index.html and 3 other pages
69748ca Initial commit
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196578/13881506), I understand that

- `HEAD` refers to the commit that my repo is currently pointing at
- `main` is the branch
- `origin` refers to the remote repo

What I don't understand is the difference between the `->` notation (e.g. `HEAD -> main`) vs the `/` notation (e.g. `origin/main` and `origin/HEAD`). What does each thing mean?

- `HEAD -> main`
- `origin/main`
- `origin/HEAD`

Comment: `origin/main` is a branch, `main` is a branch, `HEAD` points to `main`.

Comment: @tkausl thanks! So `origin/main` denotes the remote branch, `main` denotes the local branch. `HEAD` is a pointer and it is pointing to `main`, the local branch. Then, is the notation inconsistent? If `origin/main` denotes a branch, then what does `origin/HEAD` denote? `HEAD` is not a branch. It's also not a commit. I'm probably just getting hung up on inconsistent notation.

Comment: `HEAD refers to the commit that my repo is currently pointing at`.... well, you might have already assimilated the concept but that wording is not accurate. A single repo can have multiple `HEADS` (courtesy of `worktrees`).... so, `HEAD` is always where the current worktree is pointing to. I just tested creating a second worktree using some random commit and by going there and doing a log, `HEAD` was pointing ot that random commit that is checked out in that worktree, which is different from `HEAD` in the default worktree (all of it in the same repo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEAD` is **always** where you are standing (very different concept from svn's `HEAD`, just in case). If you have a *local* branch checked out, it will say `HEAD -> some-branch`. If you are not working on a local branch (a.k.a. *detached HEAD state*), it would show up as just `HEAD`, not pointing to anything. Then `origin/main` is `main` branch in `origin` remote. `origin/HEAD` is where `HEAD` of that remote repo is standing at the moment.

Comment: "*If you are not working on a local branch (a.k.a. detached HEAD state), it would show up as just HEAD, not pointing to anything.*" It could be `HEAD, main` — i.e. both `HEAD` and `main` pointing to the same commit. Just a minor addition.

Comment: "*Then `origin/main` is `main` branch in `origin` remote.*" Not exactly; it's **a local** remote-tracking branch that tracks where `main` is on `origin`. Updated on any `fetch`/`pull`/`push` operations.

Comment: I that @phd's take is even more accurate :-)

Comment: About other things that might show up along `HEAD`, that's true for other references as well, not just `HEAD`, that's why I didn't bring it up, albeit I am very aware of it. That's for bringing it up for clarity's sake, @phd.