# What does origin mean when it is used as a git commitish?

Tags: git

I know that the word `origin` is used by git as the default alias for the remote repository, i.e. the repo to which branches are pushed if the push does not explicitly specify which repo to push to. But what does `origin` mean when used where one would expect the name of a branch?

For example, if I type the git command

```
git log origin..ntd-dev
```

git returns all the commits that `ntd-dev` has that `origin` does not have. But there is no branch called `origin`, so which branch is git translating the remote alias `origin` into?

Comment: It's shorthand for the remote repo of origin for the branch.

Comment: None of the comments address the question, I will try rewording

Comment: `origin` becomes `origin/HEAD`. This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196544/what-are-the-git-concepts-of-head-master-origin

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, but those answers do not mention that `origin` may be coalesced into `origin/HEAD`. Where is that documented?

Comment: It doesn't but I confirmed in terminal by typing `git show origin` which returns me the `origin/HEAD` commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [git-log tells](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-ltrevision-rangegt), this behaviour is documented in [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions) in the section *Specifying revisions*:

> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD and CHERRY_PICK_HEAD);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

Here, option #6 applies.